# Bind method to a button in android

Tags: java, android

I have a button in my layout with the following attribute: android:onClick="nextQ" and in my java code the following method:

```
public int nextQ()
{
    // do stuff here
    return answer;
}
```

Where answer is an integer. Whenever the button is clicked the application closes. Any idea why it breaks?

Comment: We need more information than this. Logcat error, code of the method, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have `android:onClick="nextQ"`, then your context (typically your Activity) must have a method with the signature `public void nextQ(View view)`. See the [docs on the onClick attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick).

Comment: In the onCreate method I also call this method nextQ so what View to I have to pass in? do I have one already or do I have to create a new one?

Comment: @user754691 - you need to create a new method. The `onClick` handler must be declared `void` because there's nothing to return a value _to_.

Comment: So in the onCreate I can't call do:
    int answer = nextQ(pass in a view here whatever that may be);
and instead have to create another method to return the integer and call that method from the onClick method?

Comment: You cannot use a method that returns `int` as an `onClick` target. You can certainly write an `onClick` target that simply ignores its View argument, in which case you can call it from `onCreate` with a `null` argument. But if you need a return value in `onCreate`, you'll need to write a second method.